# Sinusoidal BLDC LUT synchronization

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, sine

I am trying to control a 3-phase BLDC motor. I have already done 6-step commutation, which works fine. Now I am going for sinusoidal control. I have studied more about sinusoidal control in BLDC and got some idea.

- I created a sine look up table for 360° using 127.5 + 127.5(sin x) for 0 < x < 2·π rad
- My table size is 2<sup>8</sup> = 256
- Table: {127,.....255......127......0......127}
- By using the table I get a good sine wave, and I also generated 3 sine waves which are phase shifted 120° from each other.

[image]

[image]

I am struggling how to interface this sine LUT with Hall sensor angles. I know that by using PLL logic we can achieve this.

Could someone explain Hall sensor synchronization with sine LUT?

**Edited**

[image]

In the above image, yellow= input PWM to FET & green = phase A to GND.

The output wave looks OK but the motor consumes more than 10 A at 15 Hz speed. Any guess why it is like that?

Comment: Usually it is done with FOC + SVPWM, else you have nowhere to use the feedback.

Comment: Before going for FOC and space vector, i like to control using SPWM(sinusoidal commutation).

Comment: @bud Make a timer triggered/reset by the hall sensor edges. Use the timer and the assumption the RPM between current and previous cycle is the same to interpolate rotor position. Use this to simulate an encoder position signal.

Comment: Do it open loop, at this point it doesn't matter. Make a ramping setpoint up/down, if the motor stalls, then you will notice it.

Comment: @dknguyen , actually i used timer to calculate rpm using hall sensor signal. But my doubt is how to synchronization the rpm data with sin LUT table (spwm). could you give a example or small logic code so that understand even better.

Comment: @marko, I also tried to run the motor in open loop too.By setting a defined frequency for the sin wave and ran it, motor consume large ampere. And even tried by changing phase combination too.

Comment: You calculate the RPM. Okay. Whenever the hall signal transitions you know exactly where you are in the sinusoid, right? So now use the calculated RPM and the time since the last hall transition to calculate where you should be in between hall transitions.

Comment: Suppose I tell you that the frequency between two consecutive cycles of a sinusoid change so little that you can treat them as identical. Now suppose I tell you that the frequency of the last cycle was 100ms, and ask where are you in the sinusoid right now if the positive peak was passed 25ms ago? The last period was 100ms so you can guess that this period will be 100ms too even though it is not over yet so you can't measure it. If the positive peak was 25ms ago, that means I am 1/4 of of the cycle away from the positive peak which means I am at the negative going zero-crossing. Same thing

Comment: You have to implement V/f liner characteristics, you may not start at 0Hz with full voltage, rather it has a minimum boost voltage at 0Hz and then ramps up with V/f constant.

Comment: Yes i am implementing v/f characteristic and i simply run in open loop configuration . But the motor is not running good , it consumes more ampere. DO you have source for logic, that is a sin table with a interrupt function(that makes the 3 sin waves).

Comment: If you do waveform interrupt, then you can't get sine wave. Through your work has some academic value, it is useless in practical world. Six-step or FOC/SVPWM is the nowadays rule, you are slowly going to realise that.

Comment: But you problem lies in the V/f characteristics, probably too steep, since any synchronous machine would work if fed with correct voltage/frequency. You have a significant current draw, because the applied voltage is much higher than back EMF voltage generated from your BLDC.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. It looks like your PWM is implemented correctly. I do recommend writing an SVM PWM modulation routine, as you will need it down the line. You should also try and get your motor to spin open loop using either sinusoidal PWM or SVM PWM. It should spin smoothly without drawing a significant amount of current.

With respect to your hall sensor, you have a few problems to sort out. If you're using the low-res 3 phase type of encoder, you'll have to figure out a way to interpolate it based on your estimated motor RPM to get a continuous angle. This probably won't work terribly well at slow speeds.

Once you have a continuous rotor angle estimation, you'll likely have some nonzero offset angle between your true electrical/rotor angle and the angle you're pulling from your encoder. If this offset is large, your motor will spin inefficiently. If it's too large, it won't spin at all. You're going to need to figure out some way of taking this offset out.

Finally, the simplest way to put these components together is with inverse park + inverse clarke (i.e. SVM PWM...) transforms. If you have a PMBLDC motor, set your D term to 0, set your Q term to some fixed value, and use your encoder angle for theta. This is essentially the same as running a brushed dc motor with a fixed supply voltage; if you have the correct relationship between your encoder angle and your rotor angle, your motor will spin.

Comment: You can also do an inverse park + inverse clarke transform with a fixed Q term, zero D term, and a linearly increasing injected value of theta; this is the same as open loop commutation, and could be a useful debugging step

Comment: Open loop in the sense, by driving the motor with 3 sin wave (120 degree shifted each other) with getting the knowledge of Hall sensor (RPM data). Right?

Comment: yep, or with 3 svm voltage waveforms and no knowledge of the sensor data. bonus points if you are generating those waveforms from inverse park

Comment: Yes i done in open loop configuration, and the output waveform is attached in the edited content. But still my motor sucks more than 10 amp. And what is inverse park basically.

Comment: lower your equivalent phase voltage when you're doing open loop commutation, your current draw will go down. As for inverse park, that answer is too large to put in a comment. If you're still confused after researching it a bit, post another question to SE